# Замедлить прокрутку определённого блока на величину коэффициента

Tags: javascript, jquery, прокрутка

Есть центральный блок контента и есть правый сайдбар. Необходимо замедлить прокрутку правого сайдбара на величину разницы их высот. Прокрутка обоих блоков должна заканчиваться в одном и том же месте, "приходить к финишу" одновременно

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var content_height = $('.content').height(); // получаем высоту контента
var sidebar_height = $('.sidebar').height(); // получаем высоту сайдбара
var slow_ratio = Math.round(parseInt(content_height)/parseInt(sidebar_height));  //рассчитываем коэффициент замедления

if(slow_ratio > 1){
// если разница больше 1, то нужно замедлить прокрутку $('.sidebar') в slow_ratio раз, то есть оба блока должны "приходить к финишу" одновременно, так сказать
}
});
```

Comment: Позвольте уточнить, а почему бы не воспользоваться готовым плагином? С целью изучения хотите сами сделать?

Comment: На готовый плагин не наткнулся. Есть варианты кода, при котором отдельный блок тормозиться при прокрутке страницы до него. И основаны они на изменении величины отступа при фиксированном позиционировании.Не люблю, когда в плагине много лишнего кода, хотелось бы только то, что нужно. Да и опыт, конечно, лишним не будет!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используй `data-scroll-speed` в нужном блоке. Соотношение высот блоков сам подсчитай.

***Пример:***

```js
$.fn.moveIt = function(){
  var $window = $(window);
  var instances = [];
  
  $(this).each(function(){
    instances.push(new moveItItem($(this)));
  });
  
  window.onscroll = function(){
    var scrollTop = $window.scrollTop();
    instances.forEach(function(inst){
      inst.update(scrollTop);
    });
  }
}

var moveItItem = function(el){
  this.el = $(el);
  this.speed = parseInt(this.el.attr('data-scroll-speed'));
};

moveItItem.prototype.update = function(scrollTop){
  var pos = scrollTop / this.speed;
  this.el.css('transform', 'translateY(' + -pos + 'px)');
};

$(function(){
  $('[data-scroll-speed]').moveIt();
});
```

```css
.content {
  height: 3000px;
}

.wrapper {
  position: fixed;
}

.wrapper .box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  line-height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 160%;
  color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  background: #ff8330;
}

.wrapper .box:nth-of-type(2) {
  left: 100px;
  background: #E01B5D;
}

.wrapper .box:nth-of-type(3) {
  left: 200px;
  background: #30FFFF;
}

.wrapper .box:nth-of-type(4) {
  left: 300px;
  background: #B3FF30;
}

.wrapper .box:nth-of-type(5) {
  left: 400px;
  background: #308AFF;
}

.wrapper .box:nth-of-type(6) {
  left: 500px;
  background: #1BE059;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="box" data-scroll-speed="2">S</div>
    <div class="box" data-scroll-speed="3">C</div>
    <div class="box" data-scroll-speed="6">R</div>
    <div class="box" data-scroll-speed="5">O</div>
    <div class="box" data-scroll-speed="9">L</div>
    <div class="box" data-scroll-speed="4">L</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

***Пример*** добавления атрибута средствами `javascript`:

```
document.getElementsByID("your-block").setAttribute("data-scroll-speed", "your-value");
```

Comment: Спасибо. А чем переменная плоха? Блок получаю ajaxом, потом считаю его высоту и получаю разницу между блоком контента, ничего не мешает её записать в атрибут `data-scroll-speed`, конечно. Скрипт не проверяли  при обновлении прокрученной страницы?

Comment: @Torawhite Переменная ничем не плоха, вы так же ее можете вставить в атрибут `data-scroll-speed='your value'`, средствами `javascript`

Comment: @Torawhite Добавил пример добавления атрибута `data-scroll-speed`

Comment: Спасибо большое. Главное, чтобы скрипт отработал при обновлении прокрученной страницы. Сейчас буду пробовать